# Not include listing in list of listing

Tags: listings

I would not add to list of listing some of my listings. For example I import my `matlab` file through `\lstinputlisting`. What command I should use to not add that code to list of listing?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option `nolol`, see "5.7 Captions" of [`listings`' documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: should be `nolol` (?)... please show how to use it

Comment: @m13r Answer is updated to the current `listings` 2015/06/04 Version 1.6.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you right, you want a special listing not listed in the list of listings. Just use the option `nolol` for `\lstinputlisting`. I used a fictive file `Test.pas`. Please change to what you need.

A short MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings                                % Table of listings
\lstinputlisting[language=Pascal]{Test.pas}       % listed!
\lstinputlisting[language=Pascal,nolol]{Test.pas} % not listed!   
\end{document}
```